# Passport strategy for authenticating with LinkedIn using the OAuth 1.0a API return undefined email on save User

Tags: node.js, mongodb, oauth, passport.js

I am beginner in node.js development and trying to build an application based on Express framework. I implemented passport-local passport-facebook and passport-linkedin for the users to sign up and log in to the application as well as linking multiple social account to a single user account in mongoDb (from this [tutorial](https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/tree/linking)).

My problem is that I always get undefined e-mail field when using passport-linkedin even if i can get firstname and lastname with a correctly authenticated user.

passport.js

```
passport.use(new LinkedinStrategy({
consumerKey     : configAuth.linkedinAuth.consumerKey,
consumerSecret  : configAuth.linkedinAuth.consumerSecret,
callbackURL     : configAuth.linkedinAuth.callbackURL,
passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)
},
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
  // asynchronous
  process.nextTick(function() {
   // check if the user is already logged in
   if (!req.user) {
    User.findOne({ 'linkedin.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (user) {
        // if there is a user id already but no token (user was linked at one point and then removed)
        if (!user.linkedin.token) {
        [...]
        } else {
         // if there is no user, create them
         var newUser                  = new User();
         newUser.linkedin.id          = profile.id;
         newUser.linkedin.token       = token;
         newUser.linkedin.firstname   = profile.name.givenName;
         newUser.linkedin.lastname    = profile.name.familyName;
         newUser.linkedin.email       = profile.emails;
         newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            return done(null, newUser);
         });
        }
      });
    } else {
    // user already exists and is logged in, we have to link accounts
    [...]
  }
 });
}));
```

routes/accounts.js

```
// linkedin --------------------------------
// send to linkedin to do the authentication
app.get('/auth/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin', { scope: ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'] }));

// handle the callback after linkedin has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback',
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
```

I could find firstname and lastname to save into my User database from looking at Passport-LinkedIn/lib/[strategy.js](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-linkedin/blob/master/lib/strategy.js), then I did the same with profile.emails bit still remains "undefined" after authenticating proprely the user.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Edit: From LinkedIn Developer FAQ**

> While we have not announced the official deprecation of OAuth 1.0a in
>   conjunction with LinkedIn's APIs, we no longer actively encourage or
>   support its use.
>
> Existing applications built with OAuth 1.0a will continue to
>   functional normally until such time as we officially announce its
>   sunset.
>
> Using or transitioning to OAuth 2.0 is strongly encouraged for all
>   applications.

Comment: some one please help me with this :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982994/difference-between-oauth-shim-oauth-signature-and-oauth-request-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue a while back and now got it working. Have you tried with [oauth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2)? If you have already implemented passport-linkedin then this should be minor changes for your passport.js file.
OAuth 1.0 was deprecated by Linkedin, hence why it may causes some issues to retrieve some information. I guess you're facing the same situation. Try this and you should be good to go!

Comment: I've done it with passport-linkedin-oauth2 and it works perfectly fine! Thank you!